# How to deploy Logic App to Azure with ARM template that posts messages to Slack?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am using the following ARM-template to make a Logic App that posts a message to Slack. However, when it gets deployed I get a Post-message "connection not found" (see image).

What is wrong with the template causing me to get connection not found?

```
{
"$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "parameters":{
       "slack":{
          "defaultValue":"",
          "type":"Object"
       }
    },
    "triggers":{
       "manual":{
          "inputs":{
             "schema":{
                "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                "properties":{
                   "context":{
                      "properties":{
                         "name":{
                            "type":"string"
                         },
                         "portalLink":{
                            "type":"string"
                         },
                         "resourceName":{
                            "type":"string"
                         }
                      },
                      "required":[
                         "name",
                         "portalLink",
                         "resourceName"
                      ],
                      "type":"object"
                   },
                   "status":{
                      "type":"string"
                   }
                },
                "required":[
                   "status",
                   "context"
                ],
                "type":"object"
             }
          },
          "kind":"Http",
          "type":"Request"
       }
    },
    "actions":{
       "Post_message":{
          "runAfter":{
 
          },
          "type":"ApiConnection",
          "inputs":{
             "host":{
                "connection":{
                   "name":"Hard-coded name here"
                }
             },
             "method":"post",
             "path":"/chat.postMessage",
             "queries":{
                "channel":"slack-channel-name",
                "text":"This is a test :) "
             }
          }
       }
    },
    "outputs":{
 
    }
 }
```

I am adding the parameters with a Python workflow-package in a separate script, imported from:

```
azure.mgmt.logic.models import Workflow
```

This seems to be working ok as the Logic App gets deployed just fine, it is only the connection that is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring, because you have not created a `Slack connector` and added it's details in the Logic App. The Logic App ARM for this shall look something like:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Post_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['slack']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/chat.postMessage",
                    "queries": {
                        "channel": "C0N******UT",
                        "text": "Hello there!"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "slack": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b8*******23f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/slack",
                    "connectionName": "slack",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed************4c23f/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus2/managedApis/slack"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The slack connector should be added here:

[image]